# SELECT .. JOIN para relacionar 2 tablas

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Buenas noches, tengo un problema ya que actualmente poseo dos tablas en mysql y al momento de realizar la consulta no puedo hacer que estas me muestren todos sus datos ya que no se como relacionarlas. Las claves primarias son CedulaAlumno y CedulaRepresentante, que ocurre con esto? que los datos nunca serán iguales y por ende no se como asociarlos para obtener los resultados. Aquí dejo el código y las pantallas de la base de datos. Muchas gracias.

PD:Como veran no se donde debo colocar el inner join si es que debo colocarlo.

**Tabla alumnos**

[image: La primera pertenece a la tabla alumnos]

**Tabla representantes**

[image: La segunda a la de representantes]

A continuación el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consulta de Registros</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$Conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tesis") or die ("Problemas con la conexion");

$Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select TipoCedulaAlumno, CedulaAlumno, PrimerApellidoAlumno, SegundoApellidoAlumno, PrimerNombreAlumno, SegundoNombreAlumno, FechaNacimientoAlumno, NacionalidadAlumno, EdadAlumno, SexoAlumno, DireccionAlumno, TelefonoAlumno, CorreoAlumno from alumnos where CedulaAlumno = '$_REQUEST[CedulaAlumno]'") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

if ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

{
    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Fecha de Nacimiento del Alumno: ".$Reg['FechaNacimientoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nacionalidad del Alumno: ".$Reg['NacionalidadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad del Alumno: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Sexo del Alumno: ".$Reg['SexoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Direccion del Alumno: ".$Reg['DireccionAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Telefono del Alumno: ".$Reg['TelefonoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Correo del Alumno: ".$Reg['CorreoAlumno']."<br>";

}

else 

{
 echo "No se encontro un alumno con esa Cedula";
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué es un representante? Me refiero en relación con el alumno.

Comment: @Shaz es quien lo inscribe en la universidad o colegio

Comment: Te recomiendo que visites la pag phpya quizás te solucione en algo

Comment: Te recomiendo que especifiques mejor el titulo pues no se sabe que problema tienes hasta que entras a leerlo todo. Si quieres más visitas y mas respuestas es mejor aclarar de entrada un poco de que va tu problema.     Saludos.

Comment: yo me estudie los módulos de esa pagina y me sirvieron de mucho, pero solo cuando trabajo en dos tablas, mas de dos no tienen informacion

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que el campo cedulaAlumnoRepresentante de la tabla representates és FK hace referencia a la clave primaria de la tabla alumno al que representa.

Para ver todos los datos del alumno + todos los datos del representante (en caso que lo haya) debes usar esta SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM alumnos LEFT JOIN representantes 
ON alumnos.CedulaAlumno = representantes.cedulaAlumnoRepresentante
```

Answer (score -2):

Creo que estas malinterpretando las cosas, pues mira, a lo que veo las 2 tablas tienen una relación a lo que es persona, osea... son personas!..
Pues lo que yo haría es lo siguiente, me crearía una tabla llamada `PERSONA`, donde contendría lo simple: `id_persona, Nombre, Apellido, año_nacimiento,` etc.

Luego crearía otra tabla `ALUMNO`, donde contendría sus propios campos: `id_alumno,fk_carrera,fk_id_persona`(este es el id de la persona),`fk_representante`(aquí estará un ID de PERSONA)

SI necesitas mas ayuda, puedo asesorarte via skype: desarrollador_01